# How to include QR in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Gazebo Users!
Could it be possible to include QR (or AR) markers in gazebo world? How?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8828/how-to-include-qr-in-gazebo/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1134/rahndall/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
If you want I created python scripts to automatically generate AR tags models in gazebo. This might save you some time : https://github.com/keulYSMB/gazebo_models

Method used: texture square in blender and generate sdf files accordingly.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1014/marguedas/) with karma: 26 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1134/rahndall/) on 2017-02-10**:
Many thanks!